# Show these sets are homeomorphic to eachother

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

1) {${(x, y) ∈ R^2 |0 < x^2 + y^2 < 1}$}

2) {${(x, y) ∈ R^2 | x^2 + y^2 > 1}$}

I've considered mapping r to 1/r, from (0,1) to (1,∞)

Comment: Here's a hint: use the map $f:\mathbb R \setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb R \setminus \{0\},\ x \mapsto \frac{x}{\|x\|^2}.$

Comment: Think in polar coordinates.

Comment: @jflipp is this x you're mapping the x from the (x,y) or is it the radius?

Comment: What was I thinking? I really meant $f:\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb R^2\setminus \{0\}, x \mapsto \frac{x}{\|x\|^2}.$ So it's $x \in \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}.$

Comment: @jflipp So we need not worry about the y coordinates? If i can prove that the map you stated is continuous and bijective, and its inverse is continuous, then we have a homeomorphism
?

Comment: @jflipp why would you map x to $x/||x||^2$ as opposed to $1/x$ ?

Comment: The notation $x\in \Bbb R^2\setminus \{0\}$ implies that $x=(x_1,x_2)$. Hence $x$ in jflipp's comments is really the same as $(x,y)$ in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your original idea is right on the mark. Let $z=re^{it}$. Then the map 
$$z\mapsto \frac{1}{z}$$
or equivalently
$$z\mapsto \frac{1}{r}e^{-it}$$
will do the trick.

If we want to "keep it real," the map is
$$(r\cos(t),r\sin(t))\mapsto ( \frac{1}{r} \cos(t) , -\frac{1}{r} \sin(t))$$
The minus sign is for convenience in the easier definition but is not strictly necessary.

Comment: So i've used the real map, and easily proven its bijective. What i'm struggling with is proving continuity.

Comment: The component functions are continuous. It is sufficient to show that the inverse image of a basic open set is open, and you can use products of open sets in the real line as your basis elements.